# Why aren't there any SuperUser users with a Beta badge?

Tags: support, status-completed, badges, beta

Why aren't there any SuperUser users with a Beta badge?

Comment: "I don't need no stinking badges!" But in this case I do want it!

Comment: How long now before someone complains about there being a long list of Beta badged?

Comment: ALL YOUR BADGE ARE BELONG TO US

Comment: Found the critera: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7809/superuser-beta-badge

Answer (score 6):

Beta badge is being awarded now. I got mine when I logged in.

Comment: That's why it is flagged 'status completed'.

Comment: yup, just got mine too!

Comment: I can see it now. ZOMG!

Comment: Do you have to logout and log back in to trigger it?

Comment: I didn't have to do any logging out or logging in.

Comment: @TheTXI: Huh.  I wonder if I just didn't qualify or something.

Comment: Hm.  I provided answers on SU, but no questions.  I see users with rep as low as 11 with the badge, but it seems they all asked at least one question, and may not have given any answers.  Was asking a question during the beta one of the requirements for the badge?

Comment: Nope, that's not it: [2 answers, rep of 1](http://superuser.com/users/3567/david-reis)  Oh well, it probably wasn't _real_ silver anyway... ;)

Comment: I didn't get one either.  I wonder what the criteria was.

Comment: Tracy: You should receive a beta badge once you hit 100 rep I believe. The 100 rep thing is usually to prevent dummy accounts and all the 1 reppers who never were active from actually getting the badge.

Comment: TheTXI: How does that explain some users with 1 rep.  Granted, my only answers and upvotes are on wiki, and it's not the end of the world.  Just confusing.  Oh, who am I kidding?  I'm whining.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I only had *2* badges and not 3.

Comment: 100 rep had nothing to do with it -- just the number of bronze badges.  So I missed out; oh well.

Answer (score 3):

It might just be waiting to be kicked into gear. So, patience.

Of course, the Beta badge might have just asked the [Enthusiast badge to change shifts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14124/enthusiast-badge-too-enthusiastic) while it had to take an emergency personal day.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, that explains why I suddenly got a Beta badge on SuperUser. :-)